# Coloring the area between two curves with bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I've got a code with bokeh. There is two math functions where there is an area zone between these two functions in the interval [0, 2]. How can I fill this area zone with a color? I can't use polygon because it is not a polygon.
Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import *


N = 300
x0 = np.linspace(-1, 4, N)
x1 = np.linspace(0, 4, N)
y0 = 0.5 * (x0 ** 2)
y1 = np.sqrt(2 * x1)
y2 = -y1

# output to static HTML file
output_file('plotting_areas.html')

TOOLS = 'pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset,save, box_select, lasso_select'

p = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=350, height=350,
           title=None, x_range=(-1, 5), y_range=(-5, 5))
p.line(x0, y0)
p.line(x1, y1)
p.line(x1, y2)

show(p)
```

And here is an image for more details.
[image: Two Functions]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution with bokeh and it is very simple and possible. The key is making two vectors (arrays) with the images of every two math functions between the OX interval. For each vector make a polygon with patch bokeh instruction without border line.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import *


N = 300
x0 = np.linspace(-1, 4, N)
x1 = np.linspace(0, 4, N)
y0 = 0.5 * (x0 ** 2)
y1 = np.sqrt(2 * x1)
y2 = -y1


def f1(x):
    return 0.5 * (x**2)


def f2(x):
    return np.sqrt(2 * x)


z = np.zeros(N)
w = np.zeros(N)
x = np.linspace(0, 2, N)
for i in np.arange(len(x)):
    z[i] = f1(x[i])
    w[i] = f2(x[i])

# output to static HTML file
output_file('plotting_areas.html')

TOOLS = 'pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset,save, box_select, lasso_select'

p = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=350, height=350,
           title=None, x_range=(-1, 5), y_range=(-5, 5))
p.line(x0, y0)
p.line(x1, y1)
p.line(x1, y2)
p.patch(x, z, color='red')
p.patch(x, w, color='red')

show(p)
```

And here is an image with the optimal solution:

[image: The solution image]

Thanks

Comment: This is what I suggested you do in the first place.

Comment: I was confused, I thought about Taylor or Bezier. Later I thought about this solution, I was not sure about this is an optimal solution. So I tried it. This solution is possible for D3 js too. Anyway, thanks a lot to you. Now other people have got a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in to Bokeh that will do, e.g. a flood fill, which is really what would be needed. Your best bet is to compute a polygonal approximation to the area yourself.

Otherwise you could (in principle) create a custom extension to perform a flood-fill in JavaScript, but I'm not sure how much effort that would take.

Comment: A polygonal approximation is not viable because I've got many more different plots with this problem. I tested D3 libraries and I've got the same problem. I don't know sufficient JavaScript to make a plugin.

Comment: There is an article here describing an efficient flood-fill on HTML canvas: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/ I'd suggest you make a feature request on the Bokeh GitHub issue tracker so we can consider it.

Answer (score 0):

There is [VArea](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/varea.html) now which should do the trick. Perhaps you might want to restict the plotting range to f1 > f2.